# Postgresql sessions from psql and psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

I am running two terminal sessions, in the first one I've opened psql, and in the second one ipython with psycopg2 imported.
I'm connected to the same db in both sessions. When I update a table through ipython/psycopg2, psql session queries won't reflect the updates (i.e. I add a row in a table via psycopg2, and psql still fetches no rows).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, after executing update you didn't execute `commit()` (it makes the changes to the database persistent) on the connection object.
See the first example in the docs http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I thought that I should use commit only within transactions, my mistake.